# Want to connect input with variable in Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I want to suggest a variable which contain data by user from input section and store it into my variable so how I can do this in JavaScript?  I suggest a = .... but that does not work as expected

```js
let a = document.getElementById("link");

function lol() {
  document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = `a`;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="link" name="link">
<button id="btn" onclick="lol()">Upload Video</button>
<p id="print"></p>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do and what does not work. If you want to upload a video to your server, you need a file input field and a server process. Either a form to submit or use AJAX to send the data to the server

Comment: Maybe you meant `document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = a.value;`

Comment: Important: Java is not the same as JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass event and it's target value not only make reference from input to paragraph.

Adrian

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

```
function lol() {
  document.getElementById("print").innerText = a.value;
}
```

Use innerText instead of innerHtml to avoid html syntax passed through that input.

If you put variable name in parentheses it will treat it as text and not variable.

And a is input field with many options, to access value you use a.value

Comment: Thank you Soo much bro I use this website for the frst time but i see Very good coder here I really thankful to you this is working for me.